# Show progress in Android when transmitting data to BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an app where I try to send data to BLE device using external SDK.In the do in background, I just transmit the data to the BLE device. I need to show the progress bar until the transmit is done. How do I calculate the progress in this case? Most of the examples to show progress are only downloading data.

Comment: Are you transmitting a single value or do you write multiple times? You can't get progress if you write a single value, but if you write multiple values then just keep track of how many you have sent so far.

Comment: I am sending multiple values

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [NordicSemiconductor API](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/tree/6011e63816b792505b68d78b1c32b572a8f056e3)

In your service

```
fun sendData(context: Context){
    val data = ByteArray()
    for (x in 0 .. 20){    // separate data into segments, ie 20
        transmit(data, (x/20)*100, context)   // current progress will be (x/20)*100
    }

}

private fun onProgress(progress: Int, context: Context){
    notifyProgress("Sending data: $progress%", progress, context) // create notification
}

private fun transmit(data: ByteArray, progress: Int, context: Context): Boolean{
    return if (bleManager != null) {
        (bleManager as LEManager).transmitData(data, progress, context, this::onProgress)
    } else {
        false
    }
 }
```

In LEManager.kt

```
fun transmitData(bytes: ByteArray, progress: Int, context: Context, listener: (Int, Context) -> Unit): Boolean{
    return if (isConnected && isReady && txCharacteristic != null){
        requestMtu(MTU).enqueue()
        writeCharacteristic(txCharacteristic, bytes)
            .with { device, data ->
            
            }
            .fail { device, status ->
                
            }
            .done {
                listener(progress, context) 
            }
            .enqueue()
    
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```